# Grouping and emailing CSV Data with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file that lists employees email address and some random information per transaction that I want to email them individually.  Here is the current format:

```
| Email        | risk_level | breach_title | breach_desc | breach_date
| ------------ | -----------| -------------| ------------|------------
| jeff@abc.com | High       | Hack 1       | Bad things  | 1/1/2021   
| jeff@abc.com | Medium     | Hack 2       | Not so bad  | 1/2/2021
| bill@abc.com | High       | Hack 1       | Bad things  | 1/1/2021
```

jeff@abc.com would get an email with a body of:

```
risk_level: High
breach_title: Hack 1
breach_desc: bad things
breach_date: 1/1/2021

risk_level: Medium
breach_title: Hack 2
breach_description: not so bad
breach_date: 1/2/2021
```

bill@abc.com would get an email with a body of:

```
risk_level: High
breach_title: Hack 1
breach_description: bad things
breach_date: 1/1/2021
```

Here is what I have tried but ended up back at same result set

```
$csv = Import-csv -Path C:\Users\jeffr\Downloads\eecpro_results.csv | Group-Object email

# Create a bucket
$email;
$breach_data = @()

$breaches = ForEach($u in $csv) {

    # Store the breach data
    $bd = $u.Group
    
    foreach ($b in $bd){
        $row = New-Object PSObject
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Email" -Value $u.Name
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Risk Level" -Value $b.risk_level
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Breach Title" -Value $b.breach_title
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Breach Description" -Value $b.breach_description
        $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Breach Classification" -Value $b.breach_data_class
        $breach_data += $row
    }

}

# Export to CSV
$data | Export-Csv C:\Rec\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The goal would be some sort of email merge that groups all records by email address.

Comment: You're already grouping the objects by email and then recreating the same object you already had if i'm not wrong. How would the expected output look like? If you can edit your question adding an example of the expected object we can help you.

Comment: I can't give a full answer right now, but you need to do something like ```$groups = $csv | group-object -Property Email``` and then ```foreach( $group in $groups ) { ... }```. If no-one else gives an answer I can expand this later.

Comment: I agree with SantiagoSquarzon. I'm not uncertain about by what code you might want to use, I'm uncertain what you want the output CSV to actually look like. It feels like you want something like `Import-Csv $csv | Group-Object -Property email | Select-Object -Property @{n='Email';e={$_.Name}}, @{n='Data';e={$_.Group | ConvertTo-Json -Compress}} | ConvertTo-Csv`, but there isn't enough information here.

Comment: I updated the post with more detailed information about how I would like try the groupings.

Answer (score 1):

You want to group by email address *before* iterating through your list. For example:

```
# Group the users first:
$Grouped = $csv | Group email

$Emails = Foreach ($user in $Grouped) {
 
  # Add "Private: " to the beginning of each entry
  $PrivateData = $user.Group.'Breach Description' | %{"Private: $_"}

  # Make a multi-line string out of the list of descriptions
  $user | select Name,
    @{l='Data';e={($PrivateData | Format-List | Out-String | Sort).Trim()}}
    # Other fields etc...

}

# Example of sending the emails
$Emails | Send-MailMessage -From 'me@abc.com' -Subject 'Breach' -To $_.Name -Body $_.Data -SmtpServer mail.abc.com
```

The result emails are:

```py
Subject : Breach
To      : jeff@abc.com
Body    : Private: private data
          Private: some of jeffs different data

Subject : Breach
To      : bill@abc.com
Body    : Private: bills private message
```

Comment: Is the $user.Group.'Breach Description' shorthand for the Group-Object?  I want to group the other columns into the message body like:  Body: Breach 1: high level, Breach 2: low level, etc..

Comment: @user2962869 no, I only `group-object` on email address in the first line. Grouped objects have a property named 'Group', which contains the list of objects. I only used `breach description` because that's the only one you mentioned goes in the email body, but you can do similar things with the other columns.